# UIView animation issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uipickerview

I am very new to both Objective-c and Xcode. I am trying to implement a simple UIPickerView + Toolbar setup that shows when a user taps on the Label element on the right and then when a user selects an option from the PickerView, the Label element gets replaced by the value of the selected option.

Currently I have a UIPickerView and a Toolbar inside a UIVIew element. I have got the slide up and down animation for the UIVIew to work. The problem I am having is an issue with the positioning of the animation. Please see screenshot:

[image: UIView animation issue]

When I click the 'Cancel' or 'Done' buttons on the toolbar above the UIPickerView, it hides the whole UIView correctly but when I click the 'Show' button to bring the UIView up, it doesn't reposition high enough for the whole UIView to be visible. Does anyone know why this is happening?

When I force the UIView to be re-position higher by setting the animation y axis value to 144 instead of 244, it looks like this:

[image: UIView animation issue2]

It seems like the height of the UIPickerView is being changed during the animation. How would I fix this?

Here is code from my .h and .m files:

.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface NewInvoiceViewController : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource> {

    NSArray *storedClients;
    NSString *selectedClient;

}

- (IBAction)cancel:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)clientSelectCancel:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)clientSelectDone:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)clientPickerShowBtn:(id)sender;


@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPickerView *clientPicker;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *clientLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *clientPickerViewContainer;


@end
```

.m

```
#import "NewInvoiceViewController.h"

@interface NewInvoiceViewController ()

@end

@implementation NewInvoiceViewController

@synthesize clientLabel, clientPicker, clientPickerViewContainer;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
         // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    storedClients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Joe Smith",@"John Doe",@"Bob Johnson",@"Joel Smith", nil];

    clientPickerViewContainer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 522, 320, 261);
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)cancel:(id)sender{
[self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (IBAction)clientSelectCancel:(id)sender {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
    clientPickerViewContainer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 520, 320, 260);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (IBAction)clientSelectDone:(id)sender {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
    clientPickerViewContainer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 520, 320, 260);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (IBAction)clientPickerShowBtn:(id)sender {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
    clientPickerViewContainer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 244, 320, 260);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

// returns the number of 'columns' to display.
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 1;
}

// returns the # of rows in each component..
 - (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return [storedClients count];
}

-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return [storedClients objectAtIndex:row];
}

-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {

     selectedClient = [storedClients objectAtIndex:row];


}

@end
```

Screenshot of Xcode storyboard: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cQlx.png
I have selected the UIView so that the position and dimension values are visible.

Tutorial used: http://i-software-developers.com/2012/05/27/xcode-4-2-show-and-hide-pickerview/

Is this the best way to implement a setup like this? I have seen other examples using something called an actionSheet, would it better to use that?

actionSheet example: http://pastebin.com/5MC9JJC0

All help or advice is very much appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Try to use the animation syntax with blocks, they are way better than this old way you are using
2. It's not a good practice to hard-code the values of the frame you want to animate. Instead, try to relative your frame with something, like the parent's frame.

Use something like to show your picker:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:.5 animations:^{

    CGRect newFrame = clientPickerViewContainer.frame;
    newFrame.origin.y = self.view.frame.size.height - newFrame.size.height; 
    clientPickerViewContainer.frame = newFrame;

} completion:nil];
```

To hide it, just change the line `newFrame.origin.y = self.view.frame.size.height - newFrame.size.height;` by `newFrame.origin.y = self.view.frame.size.height;`.

This way would work even if you change the values of the frame inside Interface Builder, or if you are using 3.5 or 4 inch display.

I don't know if the problem is just this, but it's worth to point out.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I have changed my animation syntax and it is working but there is still a problem with the position of UIView when it is in the 'Up' position.

Updated .m file: http://pastebin.com/iVT56M13

Screenshot of app: http://i.imgur.com/QGebHSF.png

Comment: The problem is still the same (part of the UIView not been shown)? If yes, that's probably a problem with autolayout, as you are using it (according to the screenshot). Are you familiar with it? Try to set constranints of fixed height for your picker and your container view, try to decrease the priority of the ones that are binding the view to the top/bottom, etc.

Comment: Thank you very much!! I added a fixed height constraint on the UIView and UIPickerView elements and it is now displaying correctly :) How would I set it so that the UIview is in the 'Down' (not visible) position when the ViewController is first loaded?

Comment: I saw that you are repeating the hide code in two actions of different buttons. Just create a new method `hide` with the animation code, and call it inside your actions. You can also call this `hide` method in your `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

Comment: Thanks again. I have created two methods, one for showing the UIView and one for hiding it. The only problem I am having is I cant find viewWillAppear or viewDidLayoutSubviews and I am not sure how to add these in myself. Here is my .m file code now: http://pastebin.com/pn931L7X

Comment: They don't come by default. Just implement one of these methods like it was yours. That's called override. `-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {...}`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using autolayout then you should avoid using the frame to layout views.

You have a constraint for the picker to the top of the screen, try animating the constant property of that layout to move the view up and down.  There are examples of it in the documentation.

Comment: Oh I see, would you please be able to provide a link to the specific section of the documentation that contains those examples.

Comment: I'm on a small device, so it's not easy. There are three excellent autolayout videos from WWDC 2012 that cover this, including examples of animating a constraint.  I encourage you to spend the time watching them, or at least looking at the associated PDF slide deck.

Comment: Ok no problem. Cool I will find and watch those videos and read the PDF slide deck. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Thanks for your advice earlier, I am now animating a constraint instead of the frame. Here is my updated .m code: http://pastebin.com/1a1BqVGG Is this the way you would recommend I do it?